# Why does Win 8.1 File History back up have a different number of files than the original folder

Tags: windows-8.1, file-history

I just installed win 8.1 and am testing the File History as a back up tool.  It's finish successfully backing up my Documents library.  However when took a look at the properties of the orignal source folder and the folder where the back up is stored to the folder/file counts are different.  ie original 2960 files vs back up 2753.

There's so may folders & files I can't tell, plus File History appends date stamps to the names etc.